# Android studio não exibe os dispositovos para emular

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio não exibindo o emulador que esta no pc nem pelo dispositivo usb no celular como corrigir isso.
segue uma imagem para auxiliar, como pode se ver não aparece nenhum dispositivos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está tentando emular em um dispositivo físico ou virtual?

Comment: @LeticiaRosa nos dois

Comment: coloquei uma resposta. Se não resolver seu problema comente com mais informações que continuo a ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

***Quanto ao dispositivo físico:***
Seu celular está com o modo de Debug ativado? Se não estiver não irá aparecer mesmo. Para habilitar o debug você precisa, primeiramente, habilitar o modo programador no celular. Para isso você pode seguir as orientações deste link: http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2014/10/como-ativar-o-modo-desenvolvedor-no-android.html
Depois disso, entre na opção programador que apareceu nas configurações e ative "Depuração USB".

Se estiver tudo ok no aparelho, provavelmente faltam na sua máquina os drivers para que ele reconheça o celular. Você pode encontrar os procedimentos para isso neste link: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb

***Quanto ao dispositivo virtual:***
Confira se você criou ele corretamente no AVD Manager, inclusive se a versão do Android do aparelho é compatível com a versão mínima do SDK que você escolheu.

Comment: em relação a isso esta tudo correto, o que aconteceu é que do nada não exibe mais os dispositivos.

Comment: Feche o android studio e olhe no gerenciador de tarefas se o processo adb.exe não continuou funcionando. Se tiver, pare ele e aí reinicie o android studio.

Comment: quando inicia o android studio ele exibe esta mensagem 'Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version''

Comment: O caminho do SDK você  já conferiu? Ele  tem que estar em C:\Users\<usuario>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (o meu está em sdk1 porque eu atualizei de uma versão muito antiga pra nova e por algum motivo ficou assim, tenta olhar isso também.)

Comment: única solução foi desinstalar e instalar novamente o Android Studio.